# Considerations for time-series

Tags: azure, f#, time-series, resampling, deedle

We are looking into using Azure Table Storage (ATS) together with Deedle (or other libraries with similar functionality) for our time-series storage, manipulations and calculations. From what I can read, F# also seems like a good choice for operations on arrays.

Our starting point is a set of time-series for energy consumption. The series will either be the consumption within an interval (fixed or irregular intervals) or a counter (from which we can calculate the consumption from one reading to the next). As a data point is just a tag (used as a partition key), timestamp (rowkey) and value, this should be well suited for ATS.

From a user's perspective, they want to do calculations on the series for a given period and resolution, e.g. calculate a third series as a difference between two others, for one given year with monthly resolution.

This raises a number of questions:

- Will ATS together with F# be fast enough? If we have 10.000 data points? 100.000? Compared to C#?
- Resampling will require calculations of points between the series' timestamps. I haven't seen any Deedle examples for (linear) interpolation, but I assume that this is just passing a function which can look at the necessary data points? Will this be fast enough for our number of points?
- The calculations will be determined by the users and we must have this as configurations. My best guess so far is to have the formula in some format we can parse easily into reverse polish notation, and take special care of tags that will represent series (ie. read from ATS, resample, then do the operations).

Any comments will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Isaac already mentioned the most important points, but as this question involves some of the things I'm involved with, I thought I'd share a few additional remarks!

**BigDeedle.** As Isaac mentioned, I used Azure Table storage in [BigDeedle](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle.BigDemo). This is mainly useful if you want to explore data interactively using Deedle APIs and do some filtering and range restriction before getting the data in memory and running your calculations. BigDeedle loads data lazily from potentially very big external data source. That said, if you eventually need to load all data into memory, this might not be all that useful for you.

The storage model used in BigDeedle might be useful though - it partitions data based on date, so when you want to get values in a given date range, it knows in which partitions to look. In my experience, loading data from ATS works pretty well, especially if you can do it on an MBrace cluster running in Azure (which is what my NDC demo does in the end).

**Efficiency.** I think the combination should work well for 10k or 100k data points - there will be no difference whether you do this from F# or C#. As for Deedle, I've definitely used it with data sets of this size - we optimize the library "as needed". Most of the functions are quite efficient already, but there may be some operations that are not efficient. This is something that can be fixed if you open issue on GitHub.

**Resampling.** There is built-in function for linear interpolation (see [here](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/Stats.fs#L654-654)), but I suspect you may need to write your own custom interpolation. Deedle does not "hide the underlying data" from you, so this is not too hard - the last example on [this page](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/features.html) shows a custom function for filling missing data that uses linear interpolation. If you are doing something like this, you'll need to have the data in memory (so BigDeedle would not be very useful here).

**Specifying calculations.** I suspect this is a separate question, but F# is great for domain-specific languages. I did a [talk on that at earlier NDC](https://fsharpworks.com/materials.html). Generally, you can either specify your own DSL (and parse it) or have an embedded DSL where people write subset of F#. F# has good support for both.

PS: If you wanted to get some more help with F#, Deedle and Azure tables, feel free to get in touch. I'm happy to share my experience - you should be able to find a contact via my profile.

Comment: One additional comment with storage and MBrace - Azure Storage accounts have a hard limit of IOPs so there's an upper limit to how much you can pull out of Table at any one time.

Answer (score 2):

F# versus C# will probably be basically the same perf wise unless you do something completely different between the two (for example, immutable vs mutable data sets). Both compile down to IL at the end of the day.

Azure Table Storage - make sure you pick your partition + row keys correctly. There is a lot of documentation on picking Azure Table Storage partition keys, especially over time series - make sure you group rows up at the correct level to ensure data is distributed, with partitions not too large or small. You might also want to look at the Azure Storage Type Provider and / or Azure Storage F# libraries which makes working with ATS easier than the standard .NET SDK.

Deedle AFAIK does indeed have ability to replace missing values across time series, and there's at least a project called BigDeedle which works directly over ATS (although I'm not sure how ready this project is).

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion of BigDeedle led me to the contributor's (Tomas Petricek) talk at NDC Oslo, [link](https://vimeo.com/171317247). His presentation shows some of the capabilities which we will look more into.